# How to validate multiple uploaded file using php?

Tags: php

I am using PHP to upload multiple file to the database. So when I check file extension its always showing me my given error message even if file extension is correct:

> File type is not allowed, We accept only .jpg, .png and .gif extension
>   file

**Here is the validation :**

```
$total = count($_FILES['client_doc']['name']);                  
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
    $file_name = htmlspecialchars($_FILES['client_doc']['name'][$i]);
    $file_tmp =  htmlspecialchars($_FILES['client_doc']['tmp_name'][$i]);
    $file_size = htmlspecialchars($_FILES['client_doc']['size'][$i]);
    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));
    $allowed_type =  array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
}

if(!empty($file_name)) {
    if(!in_array($file_ext, $allowed_type)) {
        $msg[] = 'File type is not allowed, We accept only .jpg, .png and .gif extension file';
        $msg['error'] = true;
    }elseif($file_size > 2097152) { // only 2 mb size is allowed
        $msg[] = 'Uploaded file name must be less than 2MB';
        $msg['error'] = true;                            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code by giving the `$file_name` variable `test.png` value and it works fine. Are you sure your file form works correctly? Try to `echo $file_name`'s at the end of `for` loop and check if there's any output.

**Another tips:**

1. Do you want to validate all the files? As far as I'm concerned your current code validates only the last file - you iterate through all the files, but you overwrite variables storing file's data. In order to validate all the elements you have to put your condition inside the `for` loop.
2. Because your `$allowed_type` is a constant, you don't have to overwrite it inside the loop.